# Generate PDF with line thiner than one pixel

Tags: java, jasper-reports, birt

I need to produce very clean pdf reports. At first, I thought that jasperreports was the good tool. But after some tests it appears that the dimension are based on pixels and you can't have a dimension under one pixel.

If I can understand it for a screen report, it is not acceptable to generate PDF. For example, if I use a very small font (6/7 px) with a line under it. The line appears much more bigger than the font. It's uggly.

Does BIRT working the same way?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if Jasper used something else than the PDF coordinate system that iText uses. (Which uses 1/72 of an inch as its unit, and does allow fractional sizes.) Do you have some sort of example input and output where a line sized to be the fraction of a point is too wide?

Comment: The title of this question looks like a BIRT koan...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact you can define the thickness of your line. The width of the reportElement cannot be under 1 but the lineWidth of the pen can :)

```
  <line>
     <reportElement x="173" y="0" width="1" height="15" forecolor="#999999"/>
    <graphicElement><pen lineWidth="0.5"/></graphicElement>
  </line>
```